# Android - Open the Messages app programatically

Tags: android, android-intent

Is it possible to open the Messages app programatically specifying the number and the message?

[image]

Instead of sending the message directly, I want to do this to allow people select a particular SIM before sending the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it is possible

```
Intent intentsms = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:"+phone));
       intentsms.putExtra("sms_body", "text of massege");
       startActivity(intentsms);
```